# Eclipse logcat no logs from Pixel XL, No Debugging, Phone not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, hierarchyviewer

I've tried reading everything that seems related and still haven't found an answer. Here's what I know:

I'm using Eclipse Juno, Android 7.0 release level, a Pixel XL running Oreo
DDMS shows my phone as HT6B0XXXXXX, online and unknown, even though it's a google phone. (XXXXXX are number omitted for privacy reasons.)
When I launch the application, I get:

> [2017-10-15 13:22:51 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server
>   version from device HT6BG0XXXXXX [2017-10-15 13:22:51 -
>   hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device
>   HT6BG0XXXXXX [2017-10-15 13:22:52 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug
>   device: HT6BG0XXXXXX [2017-10-15 13:22:52 - hierarchyviewer]Missing
>   forwarded port for HT6BG0XXXXXX [2017-10-15 13:22:52 -
>   hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device
>   HT6BG0XXXXXX

---

I'm not getting any output on logcat, which I suspect is because of the above issues.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Eclipse Juno is rather old. Tried upgrading it?

Comment: Devices above Android 6.0 are not debugable with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about Eclipse version, i used Eclipse Juno, Mars and now using Oxygen. There is no logcat support for Android 7.0 and above in Eclipse. You should use a device with Android below  7.0 like i do or migrate your project to Android Studio.

I had to migrate to Android Studio not only because support for Eclipse is diminishing everyday. You can't use new libraries, such as FusedLocationProvider. You need to get used to working with Android Studio even if you don't like it. Frankly, i don't like Android Studio very much but it's the way it's supposed to be.

Eclipse also does not support MultiDexing which is essential for big projects.

Comment: Wow, that sucks. I've tried to migrate a couple of times and it was an epic fail. I guess I'll try again.

Comment: Or you can use devices with Android 6.0 or below. But Android Studio is the official ide and Google stopped supporting Eclipse for Android development last year if i remember the date right. I miss many features of Eclipse, especially ctrl+1 that solves almost everything in Eclipse.

Comment: Apparently, either the conversion scripts are better, or I was doing it wrong. I was able to convert my application this morning. Now I'm busy learning ADT. Thank you, Faith.